# For those who know scadaBr

Tags: eclipse, scada

Good day!!!

Can someone give me clear instructions on how to build/ import scadaBr to eclipse ?

Im just new to eclipse and im also new to scadaBr. I've red the thread at http://www.scadabr.com.br/?q=node/71 but I've only finished instructions until the downloading of subclipse and the rest I can't cope.

I'm at checkin out new SVN part. when i clicked next, i suddenly got some error saying Failed to... The thread didn't tackle about this so i got lost.

Hope someone can help me.

JB

Answer (score 0):

1. install jdk 1.7
2. checkout new version from http://svn.code.sf.net/p/scadabr/code/branches/scadabr-1.1.0-RC
3. new workspace
4. in eclipse import Existing Projects into Workspace,
5. installed JREs set jdk1.7
6. install Server - tomcat 7
7. on projekt scadabr set properties "Targeted Runtimes" tomcat 7
8. install mysql
9. create db in mysql scadabr
   etc..

Comment: We are now developing scadaLTS based on ScadaBR on github.com/sdtabilit/Scada-LTS. Kindly invite to participate in project. Now we use openJdk 1.8